# Number of stable matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, matching, bipartite-graphs

In the stable marriage problem, is it possible to find an instance with $2^{n -1}$ stable matchings when $n$ is a power of 2 (or just even)? If yes, how? I know how to build an instance in which $2^{n/2}$ stable matchings can be obtained, but was wondering if the aforementioned number of stable matchings ($2^{n -1}$) can be obtained too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Thurber showed [1,Theorem 5] that for all $n\geq 1$, the maximum number of stable matchings is at least $\frac{(2.28)^n}{(1+\sqrt{3})^{1+\log_2 n}}$.

If I'm not mistaken this is strictly greater than $2^n$ for all $n\geq 52$ (and of course asymptotically it's an exponential factor more).

[1]*Thurber, Edward G.*, [**Concerning the maximum number of stable matchings in the stable marriage problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(01)00194-7), Discrete Math. 248, No. 1-3, 195-219 (2002). [ZBL0997.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0997.05002).

Comment: He also mentions that examples meeting the specific question of the OP (instances with $2^{n-1}$ stable matchings when $n$ is a power of $2$) were previously constructed in P. W. Irving, R. Leather, The complexity of counting stable marriages, SIAM J. Comput. 15 (1986), 655--667.

Comment: I've heard of this gem of a paper (soon to be updated) giving a $3.55^n$ upper bound: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.00915

Comment: @domotorp Nice! I had read the proof of the previous exponential upper bound (with the huge base) but was not aware of this improvement. I'll give this one a read as well, curious to see how you achieved that.

Comment: You can also watch it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmIj-yriOBw&ab_channel=IEEEFoundationsofComputerScience%28FOCS%292021